# Oracle DECODE not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle decode that is checking if a value is NULL before updating the decimal precision. The problem is when the value in the price_precision column isn't null the decode still goes to the d.price value, but it should go to the default value. Here is the line of code for the decode:

```
DECODE(d.PRICE_PRECISION, NULL, d.price,TO_CHAR(DECODE(d.price,NULL, '', d.price), CONCAT('9999990',RPAD('D', d.PRICE_PRECISION+1,'9')))) price
```

I know for a fact there is non-NULL data in the Price _Precision column, because I can see it in the return for the select statement. Is there something wrong with my decode? any ideas why the decode isn't going to the default statement?

Comment: What data type is d.price?  `WITH D AS (SELECT 10 AS PRICE_PRECISION, '2' AS PRICE from dual UNION ALL
           SELECT NULL AS PRICE_PRECISION, '3' AS PRICE from dual)
Select  DECODE(d.PRICE_PRECISION, NULL, d.price,
TO_CHAR(DECODE(d.price,NULL, '', d.price), CONCAT('9999990',RPAD('D', d.PRICE_PRECISION+1,'9')))) price 
from d;` seems to work if d.price is varchar2 data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems implicit conversion took place. Consider this

```
DECODE(d.PRICE_PRECISION, NULL,    to_char(d.price),   TO_CHAR....
```

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm):

> Oracle automatically converts `expr` and each `search` value to the
>   datatype of the first `search` value before comparing. Oracle
>   automatically converts the return value to the same datatype as the
>   first `result`.

Answer (score 0):

For Null values, use NVL function.

select nvl(name,'not registered') from table;
When name is null values, return 'not registered'.

You can use this together with DECODE function.

decode(nvl(PRICE,'Not valid'),'Not valid',0,PRICE)

In calculations, this avoids problems.

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm):

Comment: Y can use coalesce instead of nvl

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617